# Assign a role to the user who registers on a form

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

I created a registration form where I integrate Stripe for payment.

Everything works correctly and I was also able to create the wp_users and wp_usermeta table in the database.

The only thing I can't understand is how I can assign a role.

This is the code I currently use:

```
//Sanitize POST Array
$POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$nome = $POST['nome'];
$cognome = $POST['cognome'];
$email = $POST['email'];
$token = $POST['stripeToken'];

$nickname = $nome . ' ' . $cognome;

// Inserisce utente nel DB
$user_data = [
    'user_login' => $nickname,
    'user_pass'  => wp_generate_password (),
    'user_email'   => $email,
];
$user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $nome);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $cognome);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $cognome);
```

Now how can I assign a previously created role to the user?

**RESOLVED:**

I managed to solve by adding this code dopo l'ultima linea di codice sopra riportato:

```
$u = new WP_User( $user_id );
$u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
$u->add_role( 'bronze_member' );
```

Sincerely,
Feduzi Matteo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$nome = $POST['nome'];
$cognome = $POST['cognome'];
$email = $POST['email'];
$token = $POST['stripeToken'];

$nickname = $nome . ' ' . $cognome;

// Inserisce utente nel DB
$user_data = [
    'user_login' => $nickname,
    'user_pass'  => wp_generate_password (),
    'user_email'   => $email,
];
$user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $nome);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $cognome);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $cognome);
wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'editor') ) ;
```

Please try this code.